# Giving access to organization pages to new user

Tags: liferay, portlet

In the web application I'm working,

- I've created an organization site which can be accessed by `group/game/home`.
- I've made this default landing page after login. By putting this value in the portal-ext.properties file `default.landing.page.path=/group/games/home`
- I've also set these two properties to make sure the user is redirected to the default landing page after successfully login. `layout.show.portlet.access.denied=false
  auth.login.url=/web/guest/login`

Now, when I add a new user to the application, the user is created successfully.

But, since the user is not added to the organization, it doesn't have right to access the default landing page.

I have to manually login through admin panel and go to control panel > User and Organisation and then Update Association.

Can someone please help me understand if this can be done at the time of user creation? Is it doable?

**NOTE**

I'm using Liferay 6.2, Ankit P's suggestion worked for me.

If anyone is using earlier version, Please refer to Prakash K's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this association by default from UI starting from **Liferay v6.2+**.

1. Login as administrator and navigate to
2. <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Portal Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Users (Under Configuration)</kbd> → Select <kbd>Default User Associations</kbd>
3. Add your desired Organization Name and <kbd>Save</kbd>.

This setting will automatically associate Users to that particular organization when Users are created.

You can also tick the `Apply to Existing Users` checkbox to update the association for Users already created in database, the User in this case associated when the User logs in to the system first time after this setting.

Hope it helps !

Comment: 'Default user associations' don't provide any way to associate 'Organizations'. All you can do is assign Sites, Roles and User Groups. I already checked this in LR 6.1 EE.

Comment: What exactly adding an organization mean? is it just providing the url `group/games/home` ?

Comment: I got this. Its just providing the organization name.

Answer (score 2):

After adding user to Liferay.
You can use below code to add user to Organization

```
 UserLocalServiceUtil.addOrganizationUser(organizationId,userId);
 OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.updateOrganization(organization, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**Note:** The following solution is for **Liferay 6.1** and for later versions like ***Liferay 6.2*** you directly have a configuration option as explained by [Ankit P in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651118/468763)</sub>

> Is it doable?

No and Yes.

It cannot be done through configuration alone, but can be achieved with some development effort.

There are various ways to achieve this. The simplest I can think of is with a ModelListener hook, following is a short tutorial:

1. Create a hook project.
2. Define the following in your `liferay-hook.xml`:

   ```
   <hook>
       <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
   </hook>
   ```
3. Create a `portal.properties` file in your src folder and add the following:

   ```
   value.object.listener.com.liferay.portal.model.User=com.my.hook.listeners.MyCustomUserListener
   ```
4. Create the class `MyCustomUserListener` class by extending `BaseModelListener<User>`:

   ```java
   public class MyCustomUserListener extends BaseModelListener<User> {
       @Override
       public void onAfterCreate(User model) throws ModelListenerException {
           // Your code to associate the user with an Organization

           // sample code is as follows:

           long userId = model.getUserId();

           // since the method adds multiple users at one go to the Organization
           long[] userIds = new long[] {userId};

           UserLocalServiceUtil.addOrganizationUsers(organizationId, userIds);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Build and deploy.
6. Now whenever a User is created, the `onAfterCreate` method would be called.

---

But what will you do for Users who are already created?

1. You can either create a one-time process (through a portlet or as an UpgradeProcess in the above hook) to associate all the User to the Organization.
2. Or else you can create a Custom Action hook (with login post event), which will be called after the User has successfully logged-in and will associate the user to the Organization.
3. Here is a [good tutorial in the developer guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/perform-a-custom-action-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Prakash... I appreciate your detailed answer. I will give this a shot right away. But I am currently able to get that done using Ankit P's suggestion. Do you think there might be any shortcomings in that approach?

Comment: This is what happens when you don't specify the liferay version in your question :-), I thought you wanted for Liferay 6.1 but I guess it is Liferay 6.2 you are working on. I will mention that in my answer. Though I will keep this answer for those looking for a solution in Liferay 6.1 and it might help others who are looking for a listener-hook example :-)