# Adding a new user to an organization in Liferay 6.2 GA2: Portal 'Default User Settings' doesn't work

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2.x should allow the automatic assignment of a user to an organization according to the answer by #Prakash and #AnkitP to this question [Giving access to organization pages to new user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22643733/3938387).

The assignment is done in *Control Panel > Portal settings > Users > Default User Associations*.

According to the answer there should be an association for *Organization*, but in my fresh install of 6.2 GA2 the only organization association is *Organization Sites*.  When I put an organization name in that field, new users were automatically assigned to the organization site (that was associated with the organization I entered) - but they were NOT added to the organization itself.  Also, the assignment was immediate, instead of after the user logged in, which is when it should have happened according to the answer.  I did check again after the user logged in as well, and the assignment to the organization is not made.  The user is show as not belonging to any organization still.

So I am wondering if this is a change in behavior in the latest version, a setting I missed somewhere, or what.  If it is the new intended behavior then I'm back to writing a hook.